# Compiling source code for Audacity 2.4.2 on Xubuntu Linux

Tags: xubuntu, make, tar, audacity

After recently switching to Xubuntu Linux 22.04 on my laptop, I am trying to install Audacity 2.4.2 (specifically this version, as succeeding versions of audacity contain spyware that not only steals my data but makes the software run slower overall). I found the source code for this version of Audacity on Archive.org, extract the tar file into my /usr/local folder, and tried compiling the code using 'make' and './configure', but to no avail. What other methods can I use to compile this source code and run this version of Audacity? I would really appreciate any help.

Audacity 2.4.2 source code: https://archive.org/details/audacity-2.4.2

Comment: Without ANY error messages, or any hint of what you're doing, nobody has a guess. Do: `sudo apt install build-essential`. Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: You can get all official versions of the source from github: https://github.com/aseprite/aseprite